# Display calendar event details in iOS

Tags: icalendar, ios7.1, ekevent, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I am using below piece of code to fetch calendar events and to log it's details.When i try to log currenttime, startDate and endDate,it is displaying time around 5 hours before. I am not getting what is the reason behind it?

I have set an event at 30th July from 8PM to 9PM.

[image]

My Code:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)fetchEvents
{
    long hour;
    long minute;


    NSCalendar *cal=[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSTimeZone *tz=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"];
    [cal setTimeZone:tz];

    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"currentTime %@", currentTime);


    NSDateComponents *comp=[cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    hour = [comp hour];
    minute =[comp minute];

    NSLog(@"hour %ld", hour);
    NSLog(@"minute %ld", minute);

    //Create the end date components
    NSDateComponents *tomorrowDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    tomorrowDateComponents.day = 2;

    NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:tomorrowDateComponents
                                                                    toDate:startDate
                                                                   options:0];
    // We will only search the default calendar for our events
    NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.defaultCalendar];

    // Create the predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
                                                                      endDate:endDate
                                                                    calendars:calendarArray];

    // Fetch all events that match the predicate
    NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate]];
    NSLog(@"events  %@", events);

    [events valueForKey:@"title"];
    [events valueForKey:@"location"];
    [events valueForKey:@"timeZone"];
    [events valueForKey:@"startDate"];
    [events valueForKey:@"endDate"];

    NSLog(@"title  %@", [events valueForKey:@"title"]);
    NSLog(@"location  %@", [events valueForKey:@"location"]);
    NSLog(@"timeZone  %@", [events valueForKey:@"timeZone"]);
    NSLog(@"startDate  %@", [events valueForKey:@"startDate"]);
    NSLog(@"endDate  %@", [events valueForKey:@"endDate"]);

    return events;
}
```

But when i run above code, i am getting following output.

2014-07-29 14:13:57.979 iCalEvents[806:60b] **currentTime** **2014-07-29 08:43:57 +0000**
2014-07-29 14:13:57.980 iCalEvents[806:60b] hour 14
2014-07-29 14:13:57.980 iCalEvents[806:60b] minute 13
2014-07-29 14:13:57.981 iCalEvents[806:60b] **startDate 2014-07-29 08:43:57 +0000**
2014-07-29 14:13:57.990 iCalEvents[806:60b] events  (
    "EKEvent <0x95485c0>\n{\n\t EKEvent <0x95485c0>\n{\t title = \t\tMyEvent; \n\t location = \t(null); \n\t calendar = \tEKCalendar <0x9458b90> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #1BADF8;}; \n\t alarms = \t\t(null); \n\t URL = \t\t\t(null); \n\t lastModified = 2014-07-29 08:38:32 +0000; \n\t timeZone = \tAsia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800 \n}; \n\t location = \t(null); \n\t **startDate** = \t**2014-07-30 14:30:00 +0000**; \n\t **endDate** = \t\t**2014-07-30 15:30:00 +0000**; \n\t allDay = \t\t0; \n\t floating = \t0; \n\t recurrence = \t(null); \n\t attendees = \t(null) \n};"
)
2014-07-29 14:13:57.990 iCalEvents[806:60b] title  (
    MyEvent
)
2014-07-29 14:13:57.991 iCalEvents[806:60b] location  (
    ""
)
2014-07-29 14:13:57.991 iCalEvents[806:60b] timeZone  (
    "Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800"
)
2014-07-29 14:13:57.992 iCalEvents[806:60b] **startDate**  (
    **"2014-07-30 14:30:00 +0000"**
)
2014-07-29 14:13:57.992 iCalEvents[806:60b] **endDate**  (
    **"2014-07-30 15:30:00 +0000"**
)

Comment: showing time of timezone as GMT+5:30. Adding 5hrs 30 min of ur current or given time